# How can I fix - Fatal error: Cannot declare class, because the name is already in use in C:\xampp\htdocs\TaskN\classes\DB.php?

Tags: php

I have parent abstract class - Main.php, that is extended by 3 child classes.

But when I instantiate child objects, I get this error:

> Fatal error: Cannot declare class DB, because the name is already in
> use in C:\xampp\htdocs\TaskN\classes\DB.php on line 4

Please help, How can I fix this problem?

**Main.php**

```
<?php
include "classes/DB.php";

abstract class Main
{
    public $table = 'products';

    private $barcode;
    private $name;
    private $price;
    private $image;
    protected $size;
    protected $height;
    protected $width;
    protected $length;
    protected $weight;

    // SET Parametres
    public function setBarcode($barcode)
    {
        $this->barcode = $barcode;
    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function setPrice($price)
    {
        $this->price = $price;
    }

    public function setImage($image)
    {
        $this->image = $image;
    }

    abstract function setSize($size);
    abstract function setHeight($height);
    abstract function setWidth($width);
    abstract function setLength($length);
    abstract function setWeight($weight);

    // Create Data
    public function insert()
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO $this->table(barcode, name, price, size, height, width, length, weight, image)VALUES(:barcode, :name, :price, :size, :height, :width, :length, :weight, :image)";

        $stmt = DB::prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':barcode', $this->barcode);
        $stmt->bindParam(':name', $this->name);
        $stmt->bindParam(':price', $this->price);
        $stmt->bindParam(':size', $this->size);
        $stmt->bindParam(':height', $this->height);
        $stmt->bindParam(':width', $this->width);
        $stmt->bindParam(':length', $this->length);
        $stmt->bindParam(':weight', $this->weight);
        $stmt->bindParam(':image', $this->image);
        return $stmt->execute();
    }

    // Read Data
    public function readAll()
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM $this->table";
        $stmt = DB::prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetchAll();
    }

    // Delete Data
    public function delete(array $id)
    {
        $placeholders = trim(str_repeat('?,', count($id)), ',');
        $sql = "DELETE FROM $this->table WHERE id IN ($placeholders)";
        $stmt = DB::prepare($sql);
        return $stmt->execute($id);
    }
}

?>
```

**Book.php**

```
<?php
include "classes/Main.php";

class Book extends Main
{
    // SET Parametre
    public function setWeight($weight)
    {
        $this->weight = $weight;
    }

    public function setSize($size){}
    
    public function setHeight($height){}
    
    public function setWidth($width){}
    
    public function setLength($length){}
    
}

?>
```

**Disk.php**

```
<?php
include "classes/Main.php";

class Disk extends Main
{
    // SET Parametre
    public function setSize($size)
    {
        $this->size = $size;
    }

    public function setWeight($weight){}

    public function setHeight($height){}

    public function setWidth($width){}

    public function setLength($length){}
}

?>
```

**Furniture.php**

```
<?php
include "classes/Main.php";

class Furniture extends Main
{

    // SET Parametre
    public function setHeight($height)
    {
        $this->height = $height;
    }

    public function setWidth($width)
    {
        $this->width = $width;
    }

    public function setLength($length)
    {
        $this->length = $length;
    }

    public function setWeight($weight) {}
   
    public function setSize($size) {}
   
}

?>
```

Comment: Please help me, It's my last single problem. if i solve this, I will get my first job..

Comment: in your Db.php file there is a class of same name whcih you want to initiate

Answer (score 5):

Do not use `include` like this, it's not C and there are no include guards.

First of all it should be `require_once` because it doesn't make sense to include the same file twice (better get the error early) or to continue if the file is not found.

And consider using PSR Autoloading conventions and composer to avoid issues like that.